# Basic SQL stuff... Left Join

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm new to SQL. This didn't return any results.....

```
SELECT media.id as mediaid, media.title as mediatitle, 
  media.description as mediadescription, media.date as mediadate, 
  media.duration, media.price as mediaprice, media.thumburl as thumburl, 
  presenters.f_name as firstname, presenters.l_name as lastname, 
  presenters.credentials 
FROM `media` 
WHERE media.title = 'Code of Ethical Conduct' 
LEFT JOIN `presenters` ON presenters.fkMediaID = media.id
```

But before I added the presenter part, it worked just fine....

```
SELECT media.id as mediaid, media.title as mediatitle, 
  media.description as mediadescription, media.date as mediadate, 
  media.duration, media.price as mediaprice, media.thumburl as thumburl 
FROM `media` 
WHERE media.title = 'Code of Ethical Conduct'
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The WHERE Clause goes last

So it would be FROM media LEFT JOIN Presenters .....

WHERE media.title ....

Answer (score 3):

The LEFT JOIN part should be **before** the WHERE part.

```
SELECT media.id as mediaid, media.title as mediatitle,
    media.description as mediadescription, media.date as mediadate,
    media.duration, media.price as mediaprice, media.thumburl as thumburl,
    presenters.f_name as firstname, presenters.l_name as lastname,
    presenters.credentials
FROM media
LEFT JOIN presenters ON presenters.fkMediaID = media.id
WHERE media.title = 'Code of Ethical Conduct'
```